# using alot of ではない in one sentence

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, I have used ではない three times and it feels a bit unnatural to me. Is there a better way to convey the same meaning or it is okay to use in Japanese the same concept multiple times in one sentence?

まあ、有名ではないというわけではないですが、東京より有名ではありません

Thank you!

Comment: Do you find the English sentence 'It's not that it isn't famous, but it's not as famous as Tokyo' awkward?

Comment: Good point but languages have different nuances. In my language, it will sound weird and you will use a word that is more similar to "less" instead of the last not.

Comment: I think @AsafAyalon makes a good point. What is natural in one language may not necessarily sound natural in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is A-Okay. It sounds perfectly natural.